# (Android) If I put an image file only in drawable-xxhdpi folder, is it working in all devices which have various densities

Tags: android

I only have an image made for `xxhdpi` density. If I put this file only in `drawable-xxhdpi` folder, would it be working in all devices of various densities? like `ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxxhdpi` and so on I want to know if Android does this scaling job itself

thank you

Comment: Yes it will appear to all device..But IT IS NOT A GOOD PRACTICE..Image will not look alike because each device has their own resolution

Comment: Yes it appear all devices but it effects on performance ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if I leave all of my images in the drawable-hdpi folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812707/what-happens-if-i-leave-all-of-my-images-in-the-drawable-hdpi-folder)

Answer (score 4):

Read **[Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)**

> Android runs on a variety of devices that offer different screen sizes
>   and densities. For applications, the Android system provides a
>   consistent development environment across devices and handles most of
>   the work to adjust each application's user interface to the screen on
>   which it is displayed. At the same time, the system provides APIs that
>   allow you to control your application's UI for specific screen sizes
>   and densities, in order to optimize your UI design for different
>   screen configurations. For example, you might want a UI for tablets
>   that's different from the UI for handsets.

So, For good practice you should create different drawables for different screen densities .

Comment: As always effective answer :)

Comment: Hey, if i use Vector drawables, i dont have to provide different densities, right?

Comment: @Fr4nkWh1te AFAIK, NO